# Ajacency matrix proof

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G_1, G_2,G_3$ be 3 graph of order $n$ and size $m$ having ajacency matrices $A_1,A_2,A_3$ respectively.

a) Prove or disprove : $A_1=A_2$ implies $G_1 \cong G_2$

b) prove or disprove: $A_2 \neq A_3$ implies $G_2 \ncong G_3$

for b) I have following counter example

$$A_2 =  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & 0&1 \\
1 & 0 & 1&1 \\
0&1&0&0\\
1 & 1 & 0&0 \end{array} \right) $$

and

$$A_3 =  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 0&1 \\
0 & 0 & 1&1 \\
0&1&0&1\\
1 & 1 & 1&0 \end{array} \right) $$

they are not equal matrices but the graphs are isomorphic.

For a) I know it's true. If $A_1$ and $A_2$ are exactly the same then I can say $V(G_1)=V(G_2)$ and $E(G_1)=E(G_2)$. But if it need to be swapped around then I need to match one vertex to another and I don't know how to explain that.

Comment: Let $G,H$ be graphs. Then $G,H$ are isomorphic if and only if we can perform a simultaneous exchange of rows and columns of the adjacency matrix of $G$ to arrive at the adjacency matrix of $H$. If the matrices are the same then this is trivial, we just don't do anything at all. So I think your difficulty is mostly about definitions.

Comment: yes, that's how I understand it too. My problem is how to explain in formally. I have no theorem to put in to my proof to say such thing.

Comment: For b), you can use permutation matrices and stuff, but that is far from being necessary.  All you need to disprove b) is one counter-example.  The smallest one you can find is the graph with 3 vertices and 1 edge.  So you can just give two unequal matrices that represent this graph, and give the mapping between the vertices of $G_2$ to those of $G_3$ that give the isomorphism.  Nothing more than that is necessary.

Comment: If $V(G_1) = V(G_2)$ and $E(G_1) = E(G_2)$, then $G_1 = G_2$ which certainly implies $G_1 \cong G_2$.  This completely answers a).  Is it unclear why this completely answers a)?

Comment: How do you get $E(G_1)=E(G_2)$ if 2 matrices are not exactly the same? My question I how can I explain that I can match every vertex from $A_1$ to every vertex in $A_2$ bijectively.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your formalism here. You're given $A_1=A_2$, the adjacency matrices are the same. It sounds like your objection is that the *vertices* aren't the same, but that instead the $k$th vertex of $G_1$ has the corresponding edges of the $k$th vertex of $G_2$. If this is a concern, then you can map vertex $v_i$ in $G_1$ to vertex $u_i$ in $G_2$ and map each edge $\{ v_i,v_j \}$ in $G_1$ to edge $\{ u_i,u_j \}$ in $G_2$.

Comment: maybe I misunderstand the book again. I copied the question directly from the book. If that is what they means, then I think I just make thing a lot more complicate than it should be.